# conditionally set crate-type based on feature

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to conditionally change the `crate-type` field in my `Cargo.toml` based on an enabled feature. I could not find any way to do this. Is it possible to do this either directly in `Cargo.toml` or through something in `build.rs`? or an environment variable?

Example of what I am looking for:
compile only rlib if b is enabled.

```
[package]
name = "mylib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

[features]
a = []
b = []

['cfg(feature = "a")'.lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

['cfg(feature = "b")'.lib]
crate-type = ["rlib"]
```

In case you are wondering why I even need this:

I am writing a library that will be used by both rust applications & over FFI in C/C++ applications, and the apis, as well as some of the types are adjusted based on the enabled feature for ease of use etc.

If I enable all crate types `["rlib", "staticlib"]`, the produced `.a` is *MASSIVE* (12MB+).

If I only build `staticlib`, its only 700KB.

If I only build `rlib`, its only 1.5MB.

Is there maybe some other underlying reason? A cargo bug maybe?

Comment: You could try using an `[[example]]` for one of the `crate-type`s.

Comment: Never tried to do that before, but you can look at [Linkage](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html) in the Rust Reference for options. You can alternatively specify it via an in-code attribute, `#![crate_type = ...]`, which could work, or configure it in a `build.rs` script.

Comment: @SolomonUcko interesting idea, sadly does not work (I ran cargo clean in b/w to be sure)

Comment: @t348575 Awesome! You can self-answer if you like and post what you did.

Comment: What kmdreko suggests sounds like you could add `#![cfg_attr(feature = "a", crate_type = "staticlib")]` at the top of your `lib.rs`, which might be a bit neater than messing around with invoking rustc directly?

Comment: @Caesar its definitely neater, but I tried it and I get a depreciated warning for `crate_type` in `cfg_attr`. Link: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/83744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [@kmdreko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175846/conditionally-set-crate-type-based-on-feature?noredirect=1#comment132658127_75175846):

Build with `--crate-type=` as found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html)

Eg:

```bash
cargo rustc --features b --crate-type=rlib
```